# Run Standalone Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

My Application is dependent on PowerShell version 5. But some old windows system have not installed the same version where our application is running. So is there any way to run standalone PowerShell which I put in my application folder. So my application is not dependent on system PowerShell.

Comment: Long story short - no. You can't have "portable" powershell.

Comment: Did you try to use [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell)? It is indeed "portable" but it's not Windows PowerShell version 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* We don't know your application and we don't know, why exactly it depends on PowerShell.
Further we don't know if it depends on *Windows PowerShell* or on PowerShell in general. We also don't know if it requires specifically version 5 or would run in newer versions too.

---

To answer the core of your question:

> So is there any way to run standalone PowerShell which I put in my application folder.

### Yes, there is!

Microsoft introduced [PowerShell Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/01/10/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/), which started as a fork and is a cross-platform edition that runs on Windows, macOS, and major Linux distros. You can download PowerShell binary archives [from GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell), extract them and just run `pwsh.exe`.

#### Please beware:

While it provides a huge amount of well-known PowerShell-cmdlets and some (most) of the Windows PowerShell behaviour, it is important to know the difference between PowerShell Core and Windows PowerShell. Refer to the repository's README for further resources.

Comment: Note that they may not use PowerShell the shell, but rather PowerShell the automation technology hosted in the application, in which case `pwsh.exe` is rather irrelevant.

Comment: Thx for the note. I just "assumed", the application consists of some ps1 files. OP didn't say much about it.

Comment: Thanks, @Clijsters it's Working. But **Get-Counter** command is not working. So any solutions to run this command in Powershell core.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot have a *portable* version of Windows PowerShell for your application.

You also may not be able to install a newer version on an older operating system; e.g., you can't install PowerShell version 5 on Windows XP.

Windows Powershell versions depend on many things, such as `OS Version`, `Microsoft .NET Framework`, `Windows Management Framework`, `WS-Management`, `Windows Management Instrumentation`, `Common Language Runtime`, `Graphical User Interface Requirements`.

Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/windows-powershell-system-requirements?view=powershell-6) with information about Windows PowerShell versions and their requirements.

I'd say it is best if you create your application so that it is compatible with the oldest possible version of PowerShell it will run with. It could be hard and tricky, but it's the only to way to ensure proper backward compatibility.

Comment: Your answer is not incorrect, but it seems your anwer doesn't take PowerShell Core into account.